# Magento 2: How to install not enabled packages

Tags: magento2, composer

when I try to run 'composer install' into my folder /web I got this problem triggered, can anyone tell me how to install all of this extensions, please?

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/framework 101.0.6 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.6].
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for vertex/module-tax 2.1.10 -> satisfiable by vertex/module-tax[2.1.10].
    - vertex/module-tax 2.1.10 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-soap[2.7.0].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
  Problem 5
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - owebia/magento2-module-advanced-setting-core 2.1.0 requires magento/framework ^100.0|^101.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.6].
    - Installation request for owebia/magento2-module-advanced-setting-core 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by owebia/magento2-module-advanced-setting-core[2.1.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: you got a guide in the magento 2 documentation ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install it with below command

```
sudo apt install php7.1-soap php7.1-bcmath

sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

all required package for magento is installed with this command

```
sudo apt install php7.2 libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-gmp php7.2-curl php7.2-soap php7.2-bcmath php7.2-intl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-mcrypt php7.2-mysql php7.2-gd php7.2-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-zip
```

just replace php version with yours it might give some extension 404 remove it from command and run it again then restart your apache from above command.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're facing Php version issue.

As i see, you are using **php version 7.1** . So if you're running **magento 2.3 or later**. YOu must **use php 7.2 or 7.3**. Then the problem should be **solved**.

Try and enjoy